# recursive functions keep printing zero multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

I am doing a program of say digit in python using recursion and i want that if digit==0 return nothing.

Code:

```
# Q1
    # Say digit 
    # i/p = 412 - o/p = four one two

list = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']
n=412

def say_digit(n, list):
    if n==0:
        return ''

    digit = int(n % 10)
    n = n / 10

    say_digit(n, list)
    print(list[digit], end=' ')
    return ''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n=int(input("Enter Number: "))
    ans = say_digit(n, list)
    print(ans)
```

Output:

[image: what's wrong am I doing here?]

Comment: Try not to name variables with built-ins like `list`.

Comment: Try `print(n, digit)` to see the problem…

Comment: `4 / 10` isn't 0...

Comment: `/` is not integer division. `//` is.

Comment: @Matthias thanks buddy it worked!

Answer (score 4):

The code does a division by 10 at each iteration. But there's no guarantee this will reach 0. In Python3, it does a floating point division. You can get to 0 with integer division (using // instead of /).

Here's an updated version:

```
# Q1
    # Say digit
    # i/p = 412 - o/p = four one two

numbers = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']
n=412

def say_digit(n, numbers):
    if n==0:
        return ''
    digit = int(n % 10)
    n = n // 10

    return say_digit(n, numbers) + ' ' + numbers[digit]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n=int(input("Enter Number: "))
    ans = say_digit(n, numbers)
    print(ans)
```

It also translates each digit in the words from list.

Ideally, one shouldn't shadow built-in names like 'list'. To avoid that, this version uses the name 'numbers'.

Comment: That's why I suggest naming it differently, like 'numbers'.

Comment: Also note that `say_digit(0, numbers)` currently returns `''` instead of `'zero'`. This could be fixed by replacing `if n==0: return ''` with `if n < 10: return numbers[n]`

Comment: I agree that having `say_digit` return a string is much better design than having it call `print`. However, note that by using `+` repeatedly like that, your algorithm has quadratic time complexity. This could be solved by having a helper function that returns a list of strings, then a main function that concatenates all the strings at once using `' '.join(...)`. Or by having a helper generator function that yields the strings, then a main function that concatenates all the strings at once using `" ".join(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use // instead of /

i.e.  n = n // 10

/ gives float and // gives int